# SSIS how to import data from Paradox?

Tags: ssis, etl, paradox

I'm trying to import data coming from a Paradox Database (all files *.DB are located in a folder) to Sql server 2008 with SSIS 2008.
From my OLE DB Source, I created a new Connection using Jet 4.0 OLE DB Provider and then specified "Paradox 5.0" in Extended Properties but when testing the connection I get every time the same error : " ISAM Driver not found" 
Any idea how to solve this ?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 8):

Run into this problem recently when trying to import Paradox 5.x files to SQL Server 2008 R2 via SSIS in Windows 7.

What was missing?

- **The Borland Database Engine (BDE)**. I have installed the 5.2.0.2 version downloaded at www.prestwood.com. You need to register into the site in order to get it. This is the name of the downloaded zip file `"mprestwood_KB100537_attachment.zip"`.

So, after installing the BDE, solved the problem with these steps (witch i think all of you should already have tried with no success):

- Create a System DSN with the Paradox Driver, using ODBC 32 bit Manager, usualy at `<drive>:\Windows\SysWOW64\odbcad32.exe`, configuring it to point to the folder where the paradox .DB files are.
- In SSIS, create an ADO.Net connection manager using the previous created DSN
- Configure the created connection manager to use the provider `".Net Providers\Odbc Data Provider"`, and in the Data source specification select the created system dsn
- In a Data Flow Task, add an ADO Net Source using the created connection manager

"Automagicaly" everything goes as it should, you can see the paradox files appearing as tables, their columns, etc. Now you only have to choose your destination...

Hope this helps, i sure wasted a great deal of time to get this running... but is running, time to move on...

JB